# Writing a Custom Reader in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am new to ExtJS and am playing around with it, I am receiving following JSON from the server as shown below

```
{"tid":1,"action":"HelloWorld","method":"getData",
  "result": {"InstId":"1",
    "value":  [
  {"country.stateId":"101", "country.stateName":"TA"},
  {"country.stateId":"102", "country.stateName":"ABC"}, 
  {"country.stateId":"103", "country.stateName":"DEF"}]}",
                  "type":"rpc"}
```

and I need to extract values form the above JSON and populate the combobox. To do this job I need to write a custom Reader to read and populate the in the combobox. Can anyone of you please help me in writing a custom reader?

Following are the various snippet

```
Ext.define('AM.store.TestStore', {

  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

  alias : 'widget.testStore',
  model: 'AM.model.TestModel',
  autoload:true,
  proxy: {
      type: 'direct',

      directFn: HelloWorld.getData,
      extraParams:[ {'InstId': '1', 'boxid':'id'},
                    {'InstId': '1', 'name':'states'}
   ],

   reader:{
         type:'json',
         root:'result'

  }
  });
```

Following is the view object

```
Ext.define('AM.view.combobox.TestView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    alias : 'widget.TestView',
    fieldLabel: 'States',
    store:'TestStore',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    displayField: 'country.stateName',
    valueField: 'country.stateId',
    autoselect:false

});
```

Following is my Model Object

```
Ext.define('AM.model.TestModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    alias : 'widget.TestModel',
    fields: [ {name: 'country.stateId'}, {name: 'country.stateName'}]
);
```

Following is my controller

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Funds', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
     alias : 'widget.FundsController',
     views: ['combobox.TestView'],
     stores: ['TestStore'],
     models:['TestModel']
);
```

Can anyone please help me to write a custom JSON Reader?

Thanks
Phani Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write *custom* reader for that. I think making couple small changes in your code would be enough:

First, in the proxy definition:

```
root: 'value'
useSimpleAccessors: true
```

then in the model for your data:

```
fields: [{
    name: 'id', mapping: 'country.stateId' }, {
    name: 'name', mapping: 'country.stateName' 
}]
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hi,Sha Thanks for your reply. Just for my learning can you please help me write a Custom Reader. Pleaseee...

Comment: Writing custom reader == reading ExtJs source code for reader class and changing whatever you don't like.

Comment: Hi Sha, Your answer was throwing me an exception. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: Then your JSON is not like you posted

Comment: I have used firebug and was amused to see that The JSON object mentioned above is being stripped to   {"InstId":"1",
    "value":  [
  {"country.stateId":"101", "country.stateName":"TA"},
  {"country.stateId":"102", "country.stateName":"ABC"}, 
  {"country.stateId":"103", "country.stateName":"DEF"}]}" being used as response...!

Comment: Hi Sha, I dont know why it is happening like this. In the response I get the JSON like the way as stated in the Question above. The input received by the reader is a stripped down version(as shown in the comment section). To get it running, in-addition to the suggestions made by you, I need to set the parameter 'useSimpleAccessors:true' hence the final reader definition would be  
reader:{
    
     type:'json',
    useSimpleAccessors:true,
     root:'value' 
  }
Can you please modify your solution so that it would be helpful for someone. Please....